# Handling Dynamic Xpaths

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on Selenium Mouse Hover where I am using this [website](https://flex.apache.org/). This site has many menu's which open when mouse is hovered.

My doubt is, I am able to identify the xpath of "community" menu by using `//a[text()='Community']` but I need to write a xpath which also extracts all the sub links from community menu.I tried `//a[text()='Community']/following::a` but this is extracting all the hyperlinks from the webpage. Kindly advise.

The idea behind this query is to extract all the sublinks from "community" menu, print it and then select one of the hyperlink. So I need to write a xpath which extracts all the hyperlinks from the menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`following::a` would match all the `a` elements in the document *after* your link.

There is a [following sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) "list" element which contains the desired "sub-links":

```
//a[. = 'Community']/following-sibling::ul/li/a
```